# Generic kernel as a boot option after installing lowlatency kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm using varous audio/midi applications and I want to experiment with the lowlatency kernel.
It is straightforward to install:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
```

But I want to ensure that after installing it, I can easily switch back to the generic kernel.

Questions:

- Can I revert back to the generic kernel simply with `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`? Of course, this is not ideal, but I'd like to understand how to retrace my steps if I find problems with the lowlatency kernel on my machine.
- Will installing `linux-lowlatency` have the side-effect of updating the grub menu to allow me to select generic or lowlatency when booting?

I notice that there's a package `ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings` with a promising description:

> Adds lowlatency kernel as boot default if available
> This package makes the lowlatency kernel the default kernel in GRUB.
> Also adds a second entry for the generic kernel if available.

- If I install `ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings`, will it update the grub menu to provide the ability to select the kernel on boot (even though I'm not using UbuntuStudio)?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Can you use `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` to switch back?

No. you will end up with both kernels installed after installing the low latency kernel.

Question 2: Will installing linux-lowlatency update grub, allowing you to select generic or lowlatency when booting?

Yes.

Question 3: about `ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings`?

Seems like a waste of time to me, as that is what happens anyhow.

If you want to play around with kernels, then my suggestion is that you set the grub menu to visible with a long timeout, allowing you plenty of time to go into the advanced menu and select the kernel you actually want to boot.